# How to find out where System.getProperty() method is invoked in the project?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I have no control of where System.getProperty is called in the project. I want to log some information in the console whenever System.getProperty("SomeProperty"); is called.

How to achieve this.

Comment: You would have to write another program to parse the source code of your current program looking for `System.getProperty()` calls. Why exactly do you need this?

Comment: *"I have no control of where System.getProperty is called in the project."*  Do you have an IDE, or grep to identify those places? *"How to achieve this."*  I suspect you are trying to achieve whatever goal this serves, the wrong way.  What is the goal of doing this?

Comment: BTW - the Swing tag implies a desktop app. is an element of, or a consumer of, the web service.  Presuming the desktop app. is running on a desk-top that is not the server, whatever logs are create, would be created on the client file-system.

Answer (score 3):

You could try creating a [`java.lang.SecurityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) that throws an exception or prints some stuff out in the [`checkPropertyAccess(String)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkPropertyAccess%28java.lang.String%29). It gets called when something accesses System properties.

More info about Security Managers:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html 
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed2.html

Answer (score 3):

You would like to use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and its `pointcut`. Take a look [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#pointcuts) for more.

Here is an example adapted from the tutorial mentioned above.

```
 @Aspect
 public class Foo {

   @Pointcut("call(* java.lang.System.getProperty(..))")
   void anyUtilityCall() {
       // do whatever you need
   }

 }
```